# Centering within a template

Tags: vertical-alignment, templates, resume, cv

I am using DeCorte template for Resume https://ctan.org/pkg/res?lang=en.

I am trying to put some text in the center of the document by

```
\documentclass[margin, line]{res}

\begin{document}

\begin{resume}
  \begin{center}
    some text
  \end{center}


\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

However, this centers the text with respect to a column defined in the template (not with respect to the document). So the text is shifted to the right.

Is there a way to place a text centered with respect to the document itself?

Comment: This class is very old and outdated and should not be used any longer ... You should add an compilable tex code resulting in your issue and add an screenshot of your result. Mark there what you want to change ...

Comment: Yes it is old, but I really like its classical design. I edited the text per your suggestion.

Comment: \hspace*{\leftskip} or \hspace*{\leftmargin} usually does it.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?